# CoreData from simulator to device, but device has no information

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

Ok, this question has been asked allot, but i still don't get it. My problem is :-

I have a coredata application. I store data using the simulator. Data such as strings and images that will output in an output view.

Whenever i use the simulator, i have information stored and it runs well. But when i run the application on a device, there is not data. I am storing data using the simulator, and once i run it on a device, it doesnt show the data that ive stored using the simulator. I believe i have to take the database from the simulator or something, but i've no idea on how to get to the simulators database. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `User/<YourName>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<SDK Version>/Applications/<ApplicationID>/Documents/<YourDatabaseName>.sqlite`. Copy that file and put it into you app bundle. Than have a look at the `iPhone Recipes` sample code from the apples sites to see how you can load the data from a pre filled core data base.

Comment: ok... ill check on that right away. i have a question, how come when i store data into the coredata using the simulator, it doesnt appear on the device? i've been following this http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/core-data-starting-data.html but i dont get it. Is that the persistentstore should be?

Comment: Because the app running on the simulator isn't the app running on the device. You can remove the app from the simulator an it is still on the device. How should the app on the device know that the data on the simulator has changed?

Comment: aha... ok, so the database from the simulator, i gotta grab that and insert that database to the application folder, rite? once i do that, it should read the data from the database according to the code. am i right?

Comment: hurm... can i have a look at ur persistantstore coding and fetchedresults coding also? sorry for bothering you... cause mine has some issues on setting the NSString to NSURL and vise versa.